# Como cambio el color de una brush en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola Estoy haciendo un proyecto con gráficos y tengo un boton para crear formas
luego otro para rellenar
y otro para cambiar el color de mi brocha pero no funciona

```
public Brush Brsh = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Brsh.Dispose(SolidBrush(Color.Red));
}
```

Comment: Dispose? Dispose es para eliminar el elemento...

Comment: Que debo poner para cambiar su color pues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente asigna a su propiedad `Color` un valor, por ejemplo cambiando a color Rojo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Brsh != null)
    {
      Brsh.Color = Colors.Red
    }
}
```

Comment: Me pone que Brsh.color no contiene una definicion y que Colors no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: Debes definir la variable Brsh de esta forma public SolidBrush Brsh = new SolidBrush(Color.White);